# Is it possible to restrict access to posts under a specific slug?

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, so let's say I have a post slug called "/deals/". I would like to know if it is possible for me to allow visitors to see that slug and the brief post descriptions in it, but not actually access the full posts themselves unless they are logged in? Is there a plugin that can achieve this? Or some code? Thanks!

Edit: This question isn't as cut and dry as many of you seem to think it is. I'm not looking for a page restricter. I want something that automatically restricts posts under a slug, but not the slug itself...

Comment: I've tried. Any idea what keywords I should be searching for? I've had no luck

Comment: @Harry: Probably _"wordpress plugin restrict access"_ will do the trick. I'd recommend you close/delete your question, if only because you'll probably get down-voted a few times

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem right and I've tried that. But what I'm looking for is something that restricts anything under the slug automatically. These plugins only allow you to restrict things manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you. The magic comes from the WordPress function [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in). Save this as taxonomy.php (or use one of the other more specific templates if you want, might need some adjustments, however).

```
<?php
//Get the WordPress header
get_header();

//Get our current term
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
if( false === $term )
{
    echo 'No term found';
}
else
{
    //Output the header
    echo esc_html( $term->name );
    echo '<br />';
    echo esc_html( $term->description );

    //The Loop
    if ( have_posts() )
    {
        while ( have_posts() )
        {
            the_post();

            if( true === is_user_logged_in() )
            {
                //Logged in users see this
                the_title();
                echo '<br />';
                the_content();
                echo '<br />';
            }
            else
            {
                //Everyone else sees this
                the_title();
                echo '<br />';
            }
        }
    }

}
get_footer();
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Chris! Worked like a charm. Really appreciate it.